# How to stop Textview from also copying the formatting when copying and pasting?

Tags: swift, xcode

Whenever I paste something into  the Textview from an external source, it also copies the original formatting of the text. I want my swift app to ignore the  original formatting, and instead format it according to what the Textview has been set to.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: show us a demo please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to toggle rich text formatting in NSTextView programmatically in cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519179/how-to-toggle-rich-text-formatting-in-nstextview-programmatically-in-cocoa)